# Apache Virtual Hosts and mod_rewrite conflicts

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, virtualhost

I've been scouring the net and SO and I can't get around or through this problem.

We have a bunch of subdomains and a few dedicated servers. One server does double-triple duty as issue tracking and landing page. Problem is the wildcard landing page doesn't take you to the correct virtual host page sometimes. I've been looking at wildcards but they seem particularly broad.

Our scenario is the following:

-**www.askia.com** is the main landing site. A non-existing (wildcard) subdomain should always land here.
 -**dev.askia.com** is the technical support and issues site. It has some mod_rewrites for https. It took me a while, but I got it to work and I'd rather not break it.
 -**www.askia.fr** is our french site. Instead of taking you to **www.askia.com** it takes you to the dev.askia.com.
 -**www.askia.co.uk** should take you to **www.askia.com** but it goes to **dev.askia.com**

I'm not entirely sure where I should be trying to fix the solution. Should I do something in the CNAME. In the virtualhosts config file or in the mod_rewrite file.

Comment: Voting for close as belongs on serverfault.com - it's in the gray area, but I'm thinking it has more to do with system configuration and apache setup than programming...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dev\.askia\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://dev.askia.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.askia\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dev\.askia\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.askia.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The first rule redirects every request to a host starting with `dev.` but not `dev.askia.com` to `www.askia.com`. And the second rule redirect requests to a host other than `www.askia.com` and `dev.askia.com` to `www.askia.com`. So every request should either go to `dev.askia.com` or `www.askia.com`.

Comment: thanks I'll give this a shot. If I add other subdomains I need to add them to the rewreitecond?

Comment: Yes. My example only allows `dev.…` and `www\.…`. Host names with another beginning would be redirected to `www.askia.com`.

Answer (score 1):

When using Virtual Hosts in Apache the first hosted listed will always be the default for non-matches.

```
#default vhost
# any non-matches will land here

<VirtualHost  _default_:80>
ServerName www.askia.com:80
DocumentRoot /path/to/site

ErrorLog /path/ti/sites/logs/error_log

</VirtualHost>


# vhost #2 

<VirtualHost  _dev_Site_:443>
ServerName dev.askia.com:443
DocumentRoot /path/to/dev/site

ErrorLog /path/to/dev/sites/logs/error_log

#ssl details
SSLEngine on
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM
SSLCertificateFile /location/securti.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /location/securti.key


#any rewrite rules to apply only to this (default) domain
# force SSL for instance..
RewriteRule .* - [F]
RewriteCond   %{SERVER_PORT}  !^443$
RewriteRule (.*) https://dev.askia.com/
</VirtualHost>

#etc, etc
```

Comment: So how do I change this order. The only thing I have in the apache2.conf is a reference to the sites-enabled directory. I can't find anything on how to change this order, except unloading the default site which is impractical.

Comment: joe - whatever domain is first will be your catch all. To change that just list another one first.

I edited my original post to include a sample vhost config that makes www your default and forces dev. to be ssl.